# Problems Minimizing a Function

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I need to minimize a function, but it takes a long time. So I don't know if it's normal or if there's something wrong with my model.

```
u=(y0-μ)/(σ+r);
v=(y0-μ)/(σ-r);

a=PDF[NormalDistribution[μ,σ],u];
b=PDF[NormalDistribution[μ,σ],v];
q=CDF[NormalDistribution[μ,σ],u]-CDF[NormalDistribution[μ,σ],v];

c=μ+σ/q(b-a);
d=σ^2(1+1/q(v*b-u*a)-1/q^2(b-a)^2);
L=k((c-y0)^2+d^2);
γ=1-∫(y0-rσ)^(y0+rσn)(1/q)(1/(√2π σ) e^(((-1)/2)(yn-μ)^2/σ^2 ) dyn
γe=(1-γ)*m1+γ*(1-m2)
Cr=(ICr*(1-γ)*m1)/(1-γe)
Ca=(ICa*γ*m2)/(1-γe )
TC=L+(1-q)SC+Ca+Cr+Exp[1-Abs[1-μ/y0]]MC+(Exp[(σ1-σ)/(σ1-σ2)]-1)DC;

n=D[TC,{{σ,μ}}];

Solve[n==0,{σ,μ}]
```

The model is so complicated, so I will attach [the wolfram mathematica file and related paper](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14P4ns3xAutd6bccq4MMCgw4ZxUigkAsR?usp=sharing).

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what your model is better?  From the paper you linked, it looks like you want to minimize `TC`.  Look into `NMinimize`.  The paper says the authors solved this in Mathematica.  Have you tried writing them?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't listed Ca and Cr, so what distinguishes the paper model is I add Ca and Cr

and before, I have tried it with NMinimize but the result was an error like this::
nminimize :: nnum: The function value is 1.16028 +8 [364.099 +0.513643 [0.999979] ^ 2] is not a number at {\ [Mu], \ [Sigma]} = {0.918621,0.716689}.

@ChrisK

Comment: You'll get more help if you edit your question to make it more clear.  Few people will click that link and read the paper to figure it out.

Comment: @devi 1) Do not use $\sigma _t^2=...$, use $\sigma _t=\sqrt {…}$. 2)Do not use `RealAbs[]`, use branch with $\mu <20$. 3) Do not use `Solve[]`, use `FindRoot[n == {0, 0}, {{\[Sigma], 2.9}, {\[Mu], 6.8}}]` .4) The function `TC` may not have local extremum. Therefore it is necessary to use `NMinimize`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm sorry, I don't understand from where you get 2.9 dan 6.8?

Comment: @devi This is a possible solution. But to get a solution you need a special algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, devi! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: thankyou @ChrisK for that important information

Answer (score 5):

After correcting all typos, Mathematica 12 finds a solution.

```
k = 8;
DC = 1;
MC = 1;
SC = 1;
IC = 1/10;
Subscript[y, 0] = 20;
r = 3;
Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = 7256/10000;
Subscript[\[Sigma], 2] = 5/100;
u = (Subscript[y, 0] - \[Mu])/(\[Sigma] + r
  );
v = (Subscript[y, 0] - \[Mu])/(\[Sigma] - r);
a = PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Sigma], \[Mu]], u];
b = PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Sigma], \[Mu]], v];
q = CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Sigma], \[Mu]], u] - 
   CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Sigma], \[Mu]], v];
Subscript[\[Mu], t] = \[Mu] + \[Sigma]/q (b - a);
Subscript[\[Sigma], t] = 
  Sqrt[\[Sigma]^2 (1 + (1/q (v*b) - (u*a)) - (1/q^2 (b - a)))];
L = k ((Subscript[\[Mu], t] - Subscript[y, 0])^2 + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \(t\), \(2\)]\));
TC = L + (1 - q)*SC + IC + 
   Exp[\[Mu]/Subscript[y, 0]]*
    MC + (Exp[(Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] - \[Sigma])/(
       Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] - Subscript[\[Sigma], 2])] - 1)*DC;
n = D[TC, {{\[Sigma], \[Mu]}}];

FindRoot[n == {0, 0}, {{\[Sigma], .19}, {\[Mu], 19.9}}]

(*Out[]= {\[Sigma] -> 0.19285, \[Mu] -> 19.9092}*)
```

To make sure that this is solution, we plot `TC`

```
ContourPlot[TC, {\[Sigma], .1, 1}, {\[Mu], 19, 20}, Contours -> 150, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image: fig1]